# JQuery Callback with arguments - newbie

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, near the bottom the [jQuery basic pages](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works), it gives this example, NOTICE how the anonymous `function()` does not have params. Quote JQuery page says

> The anonymous function does exactly one thing: calls myCallBack, with the values of param1 and param2 in the outer scope.

```
$.get('myhtmlpage.html', function(){
  myCallBack(param1, param2);
});
```

So, I gave it a try based on [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_get)

My code is like this, similar thing, at line 10, I have an anonymous `function(result)`, but I need to add the param "result" can't be just `function()` as suggested by JQuery website, or it won't work:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var GetResults = function (result) {
                        $("div").html(result);
                    }
                $("button").click(function () {
                    $.get("demo_ajax_load.txt", function (result) {
                        GetResults(result);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2>
        </div>
        <button>Change Content</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

My question is, why does JQuery page says it will work with just `function()` without params? I have to add `function(result)` to make it work? Am I missing something?

Comment: The page may be worded wrong, especially if you want to work with what is returned. I think that demo shows that you can call other functions within the anonymous function.

Comment: Javascript does not require named parameters.  You can pass an arbitrary amount of arguments into a function declared with no inputs.

Comment: @Tom jQuery.com has been updated and clarified. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key is in the explanation on the link you posted :

> The anonymous function does exactly one thing: calls myCallBack, with the values of param1 and param2 in the outer scope

This is basically saying that the `param1` and `param2` variables are defined previously  (outer scope) :

```
$("button").click(function () {
    var param1 = "something";
    var param2 = "something else";
    $.get('myhtmlpage.html', function(){
       myCallBack(param1, param2); // this uses the previously declared variables
    });
});
```

Within JavaScript when you call a function `myfunc("some text")` for example the actual function could be defined as `function myfunc(var1) {` or `function myfunc() {` the first example just formally declares a variable name for the first argument ...

```
​function myfunc() {
    alert(arguments[0]);
}

myfunc("some text");​​​​​​​​​​
```

arguments that are not formally declared ar available using the `arguments` array  ... [see this doc on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)

Comment: aww! i get it now. I am new to it and I was a bit confused :P Thanks heaps for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have already defined the variables in order to use them inside a closure like that. Since the `get` function puts the result into the first parameter of the anonymous function, you need to put `result` there to catch it, if you want to do anything with it.

Try this: Remove the `result` parameter again, and add `result="Hello World";` at the start of your code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Now I refer back to the ajax api and the examples, I get the function signatures and the meaning of the examples!